# How can I print a variable in the node template?

Tags: theming, nodes, 8

How can I print a variable in the node template?

For example, if it's a variable of content, we can print it with the following code.

```
{{ content.field_name }}
```

If I have a `{{ counter }}` variable, how do I display it with Twig?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Your question is not clear: You already know to use `{{ counter }}`, so what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Where did `counter` come from?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a variable that came from a hook_preprocess_node, you can just print it in your twig template as you wrote it in your example:

```
{{ variable_name }}
```